# How can I transfer html table data to Jquery script in a way that I can save it in the sql database?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server

I want to get table row data in the below html code into jquery like a data table in C#, so I can save it in SQL DB.

How can i do this?

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table_GemList">
    <thead>
        <col style="width: 25%">
        <col style="width: 25%">
        <col style="width: 25%">
        <col style="width: 25%">
    </thead>
    <tbody id="GemListBody">
        <tr>
            <td>Oval</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>2.23</td>
            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Oval</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>2.23</td>
            <td><spanclass="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please provide us some more details about this question..like what details needs to be stored in database..whether row values will be dynamic..etc...It will help us to provide more accurate answer..Thanks

Comment: i want to save these data. and row values will be dynamic.       
       <tr>
            <td>Oval</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>2.23</td> 
        </tr>

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate through the table `<tr>`s & `<td>`s via. jQuery and create a JSON array with the values.
2. Post back the array to the server.
3. At server: Convert the array to `DataTable`.
4. Save the datatable directly to SQL database using `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`

Answer (score 0):

To save or insert data into database you can use `postback` into the server (which will refresh the page) or, using AJAX you can provide the functionality without refreshing the browser. JQuery Ajax provides you an easier option to easily integrate Ajax functionality in web applications. Check this article may helpful for you : [How to Save or Insert Data into SQL Server Databse using JQuery AJAX in ASP.Net C#](http://codedisplay.com/jquery-ajax-example-code-in-asp-net-to-insert-or-save-data-into-sql-server-database-without-postback-in-c-net-vb-net/)